# Blinking flash light at the time of taking image from Camera

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using AVCapture frame work to set blinking flash light at the time of taking photo from camera. In this method I am getting flash light blinking effect for a few seconds but then it is getting crashed.

Below is the code which I have done.

```
-(IBAction) a
{
    _picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    _picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    _picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    _picker.navigationBarHidden =YES;
    _picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    _picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    [_picker takePicture];

    // Insert the overlay
    OverlayViewController *overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    overlay.pickerReference = _picker;
    _picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;
    _picker.delegate = (id)self;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(flashLight_On_Off) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:_picker animated:NO];
}

- (void)flashLight_On_Off
{
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        if ([device hasFlash] == YES)
        {
            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (bulPicker == FALSE)
            {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                bulPicker = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                bulPicker = FALSE;
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any problem? Any other method to get the solution? I have to also stop blinking after taking image before pressing use button.

Please suggest me appropriate solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly the Cocoa naming convention, any method except `- alloc`, `- copy` and `- mutableCopy` returns an autoreleased object. In this case,

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

gets called 10 times a second, and each time it's autoreleased. It means that it may not be released immediately, so it will start eating up your RAM and the OS eventually detects this and kills the process of your app.

What you should do is wrap these kinds of operations into an autorelease pool if you know beforehand that they'll be called a lot.

```
- (void)toggleFlashlight
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
        {
            if ([device hasFlash]) {
                [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
                if (bulPicker) {
                    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                    bulPicker = NO;
                } else  {
                    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                    bulPicker = YES;
                }
                [device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, in Objective-C you shall use `YES` and `NO` instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and you should not compare Boolean operations' results against `YES` (at most against `NO`).

Comment: I am using ARC concept with XCode 4.5 and iOS 6.0, so I can not use "release" keyword anywhere.

Comment: @JohnPatel autorelease is a valid concept -- arc or no arc :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks...This is working properly...Sometimes it is not opening up the shutter window to take photo... It is not giving me right to keep lightON for a few seconds after clicking on image capture button.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is there any option to solve this problem..? If I will change the property inside code to access the code, Apple will reject app?

Comment: " If I will change the property inside code to access the code" - I don't get what you mena by that.

Comment: @H2CO3...By this line, I mean to say is, if I will access default property (if any, I found) of camera flashlight, then apple will reject app or it will give approval.

Comment: @JohnPatel This is a documented API, you can use it as you wish.

Comment: @H2CO3..Thanks for the guidance & also for giving time.